# C++ reading/writing binary mode

Tags: c++, struct, binary, seekg

I'm learning C++ at school and in my opinion it's a beautiful language, but I have this annoying problem. In the text book it's written with `FILE *text` and `scanf` and `printf`, and I personally don't like it; I got used to `cin` and `cout` or with the `<<` `>>`  better say with the `fstream`.

So here is my problem:

1. I have to make an application that writes data in binary mode (I have done it on half of it but it doesn't write in binary mode for some reason)
2. After I write the city (orasul) the coordinates (x and y) I have to search for them and get those values. (Here I tried to use `string.find`) but I have to use `seekg` to search in "binary mode" and get those values separate in a structure.

If you guys can guide me somehow cause I am pretty lost here. And is there a way I can get the `sizeof(struct)` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

struct oras {
    std::string orasul;
    int x;
    int y;
} ora;


void functiaPrincipala();
void calculator(float coordonate_x1, float coordonate_y1, float coordonate_x2, float coordonate_y2);
void adaugaOras();
void stergeLocatie();
void repetare();

void main() {
    functiaPrincipala();
}

void functiaPrincipala() {
    // variabile
    int obtiune;
    // ofstream fisierOut;
    // ifstream fisierIn;


    cout << "1) Adauga localitate: " << endl;
    cout << "2) Stergerea unei localitati existente: " << endl;
    cout << "3) Stergerea tuturor localitatilor existente: " << endl;
    cout << "4) Afisarea tuturor localitatilor existente: " << endl;
    cout << "5) Calculul distantei a doua localitati: " << endl;
    cout << "Introduceti obtiunea: " << endl;
    cin >> obtiune;

    switch (obtiune) {
        case 1:
            adaugaOras();
            break;
        case 2:
            stergeLocatie();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }

    getch();
}

void calculator(float coordonate_x1, float coordonate_y1, float coordonate_x2, float coordonate_y2) {
    float rezultat;


    rezultat = sqrt((coordonate_x2 * coordonate_x1) - (coordonate_x2 * coordonate_x1) + (coordonate_y2 * coordonate_y1) - (coordonate_y2 * coordonate_y1));

    cout << "Distanta de la orasul 1 la orasul 2 este de: " << rezultat;

}

void adaugaOras() {
    int n;
    ofstream fisierOutt("textttt.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);

    //  fisierOutt.open("textttt.txt");
    cout << "Cate orase doresti sa introduci: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (fisierOutt.is_open()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "Introdu numele orasului: ";
            cin >> ora.orasul;
            cout << "Introdu coordonatele x: ";
            cin >> ora.x;
            cout << "Introdu coordonatele y: ";
            cin >> ora.y;
            fisierOutt << ora.orasul << " " << ora.x << " " << ora.y << endl;
            cout << endl << endl;




        }

    } else {
        cout << "Nu am putut deschide fisierul";
    }
    fisierOutt.close();
    cout << endl;
    // repetare();
}

void stergeLocatie() {

}

void repetare() {
    char obtiune;
    cout << "Doriti sa mai adaugati ceva sau sa iesiti?(d/n)";
    cin >> obtiune;
    if (obtiune == 'd') {
        functiaPrincipala();
    } else {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't seek to a specific entry easily, as the entries are of variable size. If all entries in the file had a fixed size it would be easy though.

Comment: "P.S Is there a way i can enter the code easier then press space four times?" Yes, just paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The teacher told me that there is a method that i get the size of the struct (sizeof(ora) and after that i use the seekg to find it... but the problem is i can't write it

Comment: First of all you should not write spaces in binary mode (it is useless and you have to take them into accountwhen you read). Secondly, you should write the size of the string and then the string. This is needed because strings have variable lengths and when you read them back you should know when to stop and when the x, y begains (which have constant length). Si salutari de la un concetatian  :D

Comment: You can't write your structure to disk, as it contains a `std::string`. Either you have to [marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) it to another structure before writing it, or you store the string as a fixed-size `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you can't really seek to a specific entry as all entries are of different sizes.

It can be solved by having a separate index file, where each index entry contains of the position of the entry in the real file. This way, when you need entry X you first seek in the index file to the correct position, read the position, and then use that to seek in the real data file.

This is how many [DBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm) database-managers handle their data.

The entries in the index-file has to be fixed size, for example each entry in the index is of type `std::ostream::pos_type`, and you use [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to write the index, and [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read it.

Comment: Yes i understand that. But what i want to do it's when i search for a city. i get the size of that city with coordonates x and y and i get lets say 50 byes. and i search those 50 bytes with seekg (i suppose) on the file and when there's a match returns me those values :-?

Comment: Another way is to create a file header. first post count, then post adresses, then all the posts. First read the header, get where to seek to and how much, then read.

Comment: Or isn't there a way that i can work with fstream and fseek? I mean a faster way to get to the current line without going eachline ? I know that is with fseek or seekg but i don't know how exacly

Comment: @MirceaMihai You can only use seeking if you know where the element you want to read is, but as each line is of different length there is no way of knowing the offsets for each line, Lets for example say that the first line is a total of ten character, line two 15 character, and you want to go to line three, how will you know that you have to seek 25 bytes into the file unless you already have the position or the length of each line?

Comment: Well what i'm trying to do, it's something like this. I enter the location name in the struct, oradea, the coordonates x and y. And after that i get the sizeof struct. let's says it 40 bytes (usually thats all the time and annoys me don't know why though..). And i compare those 40 bytes with the others ones in the file. 

Or i was thinking of string.find, but i dont know how to separate the data for example -> Oradea 22342 42342342 how can i put Oradea into a string and those another 2 in int. I tryed with getline and with separate but no succes.

Comment: @MirceaMihai If the word is always a single word, you can use the input operator `>>`. Also, using `sizeof` on a `std::string` object will not give you the length of the string, but the size of the string object which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15452958/2156678 . There asker wanted a way to do search (and update) on binary file and I proposed a simple way to achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you, i checked but for some reason i can't access or make something with BinaryFile is there a file that i should include ? :-S

Comment: It's plain vanilla output stream referred by the asker (so I used the same name): ofstream BinaryFile("file_name", ios::binary);